# Camera culling mask does not exclude objects when using a custom shader

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using a shader and the below scripts attached to the camera to outline objects and want a way to exclude some objects without using additional cameras. I added the layer mask / camera culling mask to the camera which is created at runtime but it has no effect. The shader picks up normals info which the script reads.

The scripts are quite simple so I'm not sure what else to try.

```
Shader "Hidden/Roystan/Normals Texture"
{
    Properties
    {
        // none
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags 
        { 
            "RenderType" = "Opaque" 
        }

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float3 normal : NORMAL;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float3 viewNormal : NORMAL;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.viewNormal = COMPUTE_VIEW_NORMAL;
                return o;
            }

            float4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                return float4(normalize(i.viewNormal) * 0.5 + 0.5, 0);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}

using UnityEngine;

public class RenderReplacementShaderToTexture : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    Shader replacementShader;

    [SerializeField]
    RenderTextureFormat renderTextureFormat = RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32;

    [SerializeField]
    FilterMode filterMode = FilterMode.Point;

    [SerializeField]
    int renderTextureDepth = 24;

    [SerializeField]
    CameraClearFlags cameraClearFlags = CameraClearFlags.Color;

    [SerializeField]
    Color background = Color.black;

    [SerializeField]
    string targetTexture = "_RenderTexture";

    private RenderTexture renderTexture;
    private new Camera camera;

    public LayerMask addedCamMask;

    private void Start()
    {

        Camera thisCamera = GetComponent<Camera>();

        // Create a render texture matching the main camera's current dimensions.
        renderTexture = new RenderTexture(thisCamera.pixelWidth, thisCamera.pixelHeight, renderTextureDepth, renderTextureFormat);
        renderTexture.filterMode = filterMode;
        // Surface the render texture as a global variable, available to all shaders.
        Shader.SetGlobalTexture(targetTexture, renderTexture);

        // Setup a copy of the camera to render the scene using the normals shader.
        GameObject copy = new GameObject("Camera" + targetTexture);
        camera = copy.AddComponent<Camera>();
        camera.CopyFrom(thisCamera);
        camera.cullingMask = addedCamMask;
        camera.transform.SetParent(transform);
        camera.targetTexture = renderTexture;
        camera.SetReplacementShader(replacementShader, "RenderType");
        camera.depth = thisCamera.depth - 1;
        camera.clearFlags = cameraClearFlags;
        camera.backgroundColor = background;

    }
}


public class CameraDepthTextureMode : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField]
    DepthTextureMode depthTextureMode;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        SetCameraDepthTextureMode();
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        SetCameraDepthTextureMode();
    }

    private void SetCameraDepthTextureMode()
    {
        GetComponent<Camera>().depthTextureMode = depthTextureMode;
    }
}
```